# How to print and connect to printer using flutter?

Tags: flutter, printers

I'm new to Flutter, I already did so much searching about it, and just get to the documentation of the widgets. but still didn't really understand it.

just found the solution! 
[blue_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer)

Answer (score 2):

There's this new widget [esc_pos_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer).

It didn't worked me at the beginning, but I managed to solve the problems, and It printed in real paper without any printing dialog. The text just went directly from the App to the printer, and then to the paper.

I used an Epson XP-230 Series.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can use the [Printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package from flutter. It should have all the documentation you need.

Comment: thanks for the reply, is it possible if just by 1 click and then automatically start the print? coz what i look is, printing widget is creating a pdf file. cmiiw

Comment: YES. from their documentation, it should work. if you click on the print button it should generate the html or pdf and select printers for you. see the example: at https://davbfr.github.io/dart_pdf/

Comment: yeah but it print from the third party pdf application. and what i need is from my flutter application.