# Flutter, Windows aplliation, thermal printer connected to USB

Tags: windows, flutter, usb, thermal-printer

I am developing a windows application in flutter and I have requirement of print through USB thermal printer. How do I print to thermal printer on flutter's  windows application connected through USB ?

Comment: Some articles can/cannot be done, but they are mixed. [Printing to Printers #15457](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15457), [Flutter printing invoice to usb printer in desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66332665/9014308), [How to print and connect to printer using flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60614828/9014308)

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download PDFtoPrinter.exe [http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/pdftoprinter.html)
2. Use it by running spwan procceses
   https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-io/Process-class.html